# DropDownList not firing OnSelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

ASP.Net code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlKid" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="ddlReports"
    Width="160px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlKid_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

C# code:

```
protected void ddlKid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = ddlKid.SelectedIndex;
    count = i;
    int KidId = int.Parse(KidArray[i].ToString());

    ArrayList ADA = new ArrayList();
    ADA.Add(FirstAssignment.SelectedItem);
    ADA.Add(SecondAssignment.SelectedItem);
    DrawTableNew(ADA, KidId);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GameLib.Reports.ReportID = 6;
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FillGrades();
        FillKids();
        count = 0;
        Label1.Visible = false;
        FirstAssignment.Visible = false;
        SecondAssignment.Visible = false;
        L1st.Visible = false;
        L2nd.Visible = false;
        Header.Visible = false;
        Label2.Visible = false;
        Div2.Visible = false;
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        DwdTable.Visible = false;
        DwdButton2.Visible = false;
        pnlIssues.Visible = false;
        Panel2.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        FillGrades();
        //  FillKids();
    }
}

protected void FillKids()
{
    ddlKid.Visible = true;
    try
    {
        if (GameUser.UserType == 1)
        {
            ddlKid.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(GameUser.UserName, GameUser.UserID.ToString()));
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //dt = GameLib.GameUser.GetKidsForParent(GameUser.UserID);
            dt = GameLib.GameUser.GetKidsForParentAsPerGrade(GameUser.UserID, ddlAssessment.SelectedItem.ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                int kidId = (int)dt.Rows[i]["intUserID"];
                KidArray.Add(kidId);
            }
            if (dt.Rows.Count <= 0)
            {
                //MPEGrade.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                ddlKid.DataSource = dt;
                ddlKid.DataTextField = "vchLoginName";
                ddlKid.DataValueField = "vchGradeName";
                ddlKid.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

The problem is my `ddlKid_SelectedIndexChanged` is not executing. After page load it stops at `else` statement. Its code for fill kids(Adding drop down data).
 The fill kid only called on the first that is !postback.

Comment: What's in the else code? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with your code, `ddlKid_SelectedIndexChanged` will be executed unless an error happens somewhere in `Page_Load`

Comment: show us the else or total pageload block of your code and while updating please try to add the ending tag of <asp:DropDownList

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: no...when i go for breakpoints ddlKid_SelectedIndexChanged not executing;

Comment: put the breakpoint to the page load and see what happen. as you can see when you create a brand new project which has only the dropdown and a selectedindexchange event it will fire simply when autopostback is true.

Comment: I added break point in page load. it executed only else statement. it dint ddlKid_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: did you fill the dropdown on else block?

Comment: No. only I am filling fillgrade();

Comment: You are saying it went inside else statement which means its not a postback. For the first load it won't execute SelectedIndexChanged !!

Comment: I have noticed that after execution the drop down is going to first index. example if I selected 2 form drop downs it will show 1.

Comment: That means you are re-binding dropdown in post-back also. Bind your dropdown only inside if (!IsPostBack){} .

Comment: Even though i tried same but still having same problem,

Comment: Please share your latest updated code. Mention where/how you are binding the dropdown.

Comment: Updated a new code in fill kids. I am binding a dropdown data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change binding value:
fill kids value like:

```
string vchLoginName=//login name from db;
string vchGradeName=//Grade name from db;
ddlKid.Items.Add(new ListItem(vchLoginName,vchGradeName));
```